# Visual Studio truncates message in Test Detail Summary window

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, vstest

I have test which compares two json objects. If test fails then I print those json objects.

```
Assert.That(
    json1,
    Is.EqualTo( json2 ).Using<JToken>( JToken.DeepEquals ),
    "Jsons are not equal\n{0}\n{1}", json1.ToString(), json2.ToString() );
```

But `Visual Studio` truncates my message :( Message from `TestContext.Out` is also truncated.

How can I increase message length limit?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues Dig previous threads, or post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I have temporarily solved this problem by saving the test's result to an xml file.

To achieve it you should create `.runsettings` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>ResultsDirectory</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <NUnit>
    <TestDirectory>TestDirectory</TestDirectory>
    <WorkDirectory>WorkDirectory</WorkDirectory>
    <TestOutputXml>TestOutputXml</TestOutputXml>
    <InternalTraceLevel>Info</InternalTraceLevel>
  </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```